# A different shape for points in a line chart

Tags: r

How to make a simple line graph where each line will have additional points of different shapes (geom_point). These points should be of the same color as the lines.

```
my_data <- data.frame(
  TIME = c("T1-3","T3-5","T6-8","T8-10","T1-3","T3-5","T6-8","T8-10"),
  GROUP = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
  M = as.numeric(c("7.52","7.85","8.6","9.2","7.55","7.85","8.61","9.22")),
  SD = as.numeric(c("0.19","0.16","0.19","0.26","0.2","0.22","0.2","0.26")))
```

In the graph below, the points are the same on both lines.

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = TIME, y = M, group = GROUP, color = GROUP)) + 
  geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0, 1)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = TIME, ymin = M-SD, ymax = M+SD), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  labs(col = "Group of hurdlers", x = "Phase distance", y = "Time (seconds)") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

When I add the "shape = GROUP" aesthetic, two legends are created and I need one legend :-)

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = TIME, y = M, group = GROUP, color = GROUP, shape = GROUP)) + 
  geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0, 1)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = TIME, ymin = M-SD, ymax = M+SD), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  labs(col = "Group of hurdlers", x = "Phase distance", y = "Time (seconds)") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

Can I ask for help in solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `guide_legend(override.aes = ...` and set shape guide to none:

To get filled shapes just change shape 0 and 1:

[image]

to shape 15 and 16:

[image]

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = TIME, y = M, group = GROUP, color = GROUP, shape = GROUP)) + 
  geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 16)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = TIME, ymin = M-SD, ymax = M+SD), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  labs(col = "Group of hurdlers", x = "Phase distance", y = "Time (seconds)") +
  theme_light() + 
  theme(legend.position = "top")+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c("solid", "solid")
                                                   , shape = c(15, 16))),
         shape = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This is exactly what I meant and which I would never have thought of :-)
And I can also ask how to fill these shapes with color?

Comment: This is easy just change shape 0 and 1 to shape 15 and 16 in the corresponding places in your code. I have updated the code!

Comment: Again thank you very much. Everything works perfectly.
Kind regards :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can put `aes(shape = GROUP)` in `geom_point`, and set `show.legend = F`

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = TIME, y = M, group = GROUP, color = GROUP)) + 
  geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = GROUP), show.legend = F, position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0, 1)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = TIME, ymin = M-SD, ymax = M+SD), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  labs(col = "Group of hurdlers", x = "Phase distance", y = "Time (seconds)") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is some idea, but now you can't see shapes on the lines in the legend. There has to be a way ...